# Given $f$ holomorphic at the open unit disc and continuous at the closure of the disc and $f(e^{i\theta})=0,|\theta|\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f$ holomorphic at the open unit disc and continuous at the closure of the disc and $f(e^{i\theta})=0,|\theta|\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.
Prove that $f \equiv0$ at the unit disc.
My try:
I  want to show that on the left semi circle $f=0$ and then i can use MMP,I thought maybe setting $g(z)=f(z)f(-z)$ and then $g(z)=0$ on the boundray and then $g\equiv=0\to f(z)=0$

Comment: Hint: Extend $f$ across the right semi-circle into $|z|>1$ via $f(z) = \overline {f(1/\bar z)}$ (cf. Schwarz reflection principle).

Comment: @Gary Why would it help me to extend my function?

Comment: You would get a function that is analytic on the union of the unit disc, the right semi-circle and the exterior of the closed unit circle. Can you see it now?